# On which interval in x is the solution defined?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the differential equation.

$$ y' = \frac {2x}{1+2y} $$
Given
$$ y(2) = 0 $$
So as I am solving this I get to

$$ y+y^2 = x^2-4 $$

I am not sure what the intuition is behind using the quadratic formula at this step...

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: How do you get that 4?

Comment: Sincere apologies. I have added the initial condition

Comment: I'm not sure what you aren't understanding here?

Comment: How do I proceed to find the interval in x for which the solution is defined. When I looked at the solution they used the quadratic formula. I just took two cases of y.
One where 
$$ y= x^2-4 $$
And another where 
$$(y+1) = x^2-4 $$
But that doesnt  help me find the range of x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic formula will do two things. First, it'll get you an equation in terms of $y$, instead of $y+y^2$. In the world of functions, this is *very* ideal. Second, you'll get a radical from the quadratic formula, and you can use it to find an interval for which $y$ is defined on. Remember, (on the real number line) the square root operator is only defined to work on quantities that are greater than or equal to zero.Now you want to solve for $y$ using the quadratic formula, so set the equation equal to zero: $$y^2+y-x^2+4=0 \\ \implies y = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1-4\cdot [-x^2+4]}}{2} \\ = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{4x^2-15}}{2}$$ Again, the quantity under the root must be greater than or equal to zero, so we require $$4x^2-15 \geq 0 \\ \implies 4x^2 \geq 15 \\ \implies |x| \geq \frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$$ The equation with absolute values tells us we need either $x \geq \frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$ or $x \leq -\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$. The way to represent these inequalities with intervals is to say $x \in \left(-\infty, -\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}\right] \cup \left[\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2},\infty \right)$.
As @Alan pointed out, the initial condition starts at $x=2$, so we just keep positive the interval to guarantee $y$ has a unique solution.

Comment: This is Excellent! Just what I was hoping for! I can't thank you enough. But in any case thanks graydad!!

Comment: Gladly. I didn't have enough reputation before. Milestone reached!

Comment: You'd then add that the initial condition being at 2 means you need to be in the second one of those intervals, so you'd toss out the first (you're only guaranteed a solution on contiguous intervals where everything is continuous)